# How do I *legally* access money from a "qualifying account" per UK "Overseas workday relief" rules?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I'm an Italian citizen moving from the US to the UK. I match all conditions for remittance basis, and I will work overseas enough that "Overseas Workday Relief" would make sense for me; my tax attorney agrees. In order to do that, I'm going to set up a "qualifying account" where I'll receive my paychecks. So far so good.

I'll also have a current account in the UK for day to day expenses. Let's say I work overseas 10% of the time; I can safely transfer 90% of my yearly wages to that account.

Now the question: what should I do with the remaining 10% if I want to *legally* access it?

I can't wire them into the UK or they will be taxable remittance.

Using a credit card in the UK and paying it off with that account would be deemed a remittance, too (although it sounds like there are various and confusing exceptions).

Wiring them into Italy would run afoul of anti-money-laundering rules (depending on the country where the qualifying account is based), since I haven't paid taxes upfront.

I'm pretty sure the US would frown upon that too (again, depending on the country).

Is traveling to that country to use a local ATM my only reasonable recourse?